Flexinol Resistance Measurement in PWM-driven Control Circuit
I'm using Flexinol (a Nitinol shape memory wire that contracts when current is passed through it) as an actuator for a project. I have a functioning circuit that uses a PWM-controlled MOSFET to rapidly switch on/off the flow of current through the circuit so that the amount that the wire contracts is proportional to duty cycle; however, the Flexinol has pretty significant response time (sometimes up to 1s delay). To combat this, I'm attempting to use the Flexinol's length as an input parameter for a closed-loop position controller.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The Flexinol's internal resistance increases as a function of the amount that the wire has contracted, meaning the voltage drop across the wire also changes depending on contraction (I've measured about 250 mV difference across the full range of motion). By taking this variation in voltage and mapping it to the Flexinol length, I'm hoping I can get accurate real-time measurements of how much the wire has contracted. I'm currently using an Adafruit 12-bit ADC breakout board for my measurements, and I've found a way to sync up my {EDIT: microcontroller} readings with the PWM signal so that I only measure voltage when current is flowing, but my ADC itself cannot be synced, meaning that its range always includes the voltage when current is not flowing.

Here is my main issue:
The variation in voltage drop (250 mV) across the Flexinol's range of motion is relatively small compared to the overall voltage drop across the wire (~4 V in my case). I'd like to improve the resolution of my ADC measurements by finding a way to “zero” the signal input to my ADC at whatever voltage occurs when the Flexinol wire is 0% contracted before it's fed to the ADC. That way, the signal range will be ~0-250 mV rather than ~4 V - 4.25 V, and I can increase the gain on that signal to improve the resolution of my measurements.
What can I add to/change in my circuit to achieve this?

You said that you found a way to read the voltage only when the current is flowing, but I have a suggestion anyway. Using another MOSFET (P-channel this time), you can charge a capacitor to some voltage only when the PWM output is high, and the Flexinol has power:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Notice that I've swapped R1 and \$R_{NI}\$, which is necessary to make this work, but won't affect power delivered to \$R_{NI}\$.
When the PWM signal at X is high, M1 pulls its drain to near 0V, which switches on M2. Whatever voltage is across \$R_{NI}\$ is M2's \$V_{GS}\$, and as long as that voltage is significantly greater than M2's \$V_{GS(TH)}\$, that should switch it fully on. So you'll need M2 to have \$V_{GS(TH)}\$ significantly smaller than the smallest voltage you expect to appear across \$R_{NI}\$.
During each on pulse, Whatever potential \$V_Y\$ present at Y is then presented to the low pass filter R2/C1, and C1 quickly charges to \$V_Z = V_Y\$. You can read \$V_Z\$ with an ADC or employ it in an analogue closed loop as you would any signal.
I include the filter because M2 won't switch on or off instantly, and there may be small intervals where \$V_Y\$ is transitioning while M2 is still on. The filter will somewhat mitigate any error this causes. You might need to fine-tune its time-constant to have \$V_Z\$ follow the on-voltage at Y more quickly, but you say the Flexinol has a very long response time, so I think the values shown should be fine.
Since \$V_Z\$ is only "updated" during on pulses, it is largely independent of PWM frequency or state. Blue is \$V_Y\$, and orange is \$V_Z\$:

As you can see, \$V_Z\$ settles at whatever \$V_Y\$ is when power is applied to the Flexinol, and it stays there even when power is removed, thanks to C1 holding that charge. It's a kind of sample-and-hold system.
If \$R_{NI}\$ changes, then so will \$V_Y\$ when powered, and \$V_Z\$ will quickly follow. The change is subtle, but this is what happens when I set \$R_{NI}=2\Omega\$:

It just remains to amplify \$V_Z\$ into the range +0.2V to +4.8V, a range that any rail-to-rail output op-amp (like the TLC2272) can produce, and is compatible with your ADC input. The idea is to amplify the difference between some arbitrary offset and the current value of \$V_Z\$. Gain will be:
$$ A = \frac{4.8V - 0.2V}{250mV} \approx 18 $$

simulate this circuit
The first op-amp is a buffer, so that Z isn't loaded, and the second stage is a gain −180 amplifier, with offset adjustable using potentiometer R5. Here's output \$V_W\$ as \$V_Z\$ goes from +3.5V to +3.9V:


Thank you so much, Simon! This seems like a huge improvement on the solution I've been using. I'm excited to give it a try.

You could use a differential input ADC such as the ADS1115 which would allow you to set a fixed offset voltage with a voltage divider for the '-' input and apply a PGA (programmable gain amplifier) gain to the '+' input.
It's also 16 bits, so even if you left the range at 0-5V the 0.25V span of interest would have almost 12 bits of resolution.

Thanks for the suggestion! I'm currently using the ADS1015 (12 bits total) so maybe upgrading to the ADS1115 could fix the issue. One correction to my original post - although I have synced my microcontroller to only read values from the ADC when current is flowing, the ADC itself cannot be synced. This means the ADC still measures voltages when current is not flowing, which would affect the range for a differential ADC reading as well.

Going overrange won't hurt the ADC provided both inputs are within the power supply range.
